# how to temporarily disable a package in a project from compiling in Java EE IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I **temporarily** disable a package in a project from compiling in Java EE IDE?
The package has some source files that I want to prevent from compiling temporarily.

Comment: Whats the harm in removing(commenting out) the references to the package?

Comment: what is that package, you want to disable? what is fully qualified name of that package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is eclipse, try -

```
Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Excluded
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is in another project, just right click on the project and select close project, you can easily re-open it when you need it back.
If it is in the same project, go to properties->Java Build Path->Source->Excluded. You can shift up and down easily and set priorities. Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

To disable a class/package in Eclipse:

1. Right click the class file/package;
2. Hover over "Build Path";
3. Then click "Exclude";
4. Done.

It's about the same to enable a class/package in Eclipse:

1. Right click the class file/package;
2. Hover over "Build Path";
3. Then click "Include";
4. Done.